# How can I play effectively as a single Imposter vs 9 crewmates?

Tags: among-us

When I play as a single Imposter, alone against 9 crewmates - I rarely win games. I kill one crewmate at a time, adding time to the game, but usually the dead body is reported before my kill cooldown expires.

It takes ages for the imposter to win and making it stressful and risky as well. Crewmates always sus me, and I don't know how. What if 3 crewmates are considered safe, and it's only me left?

All in all, how can 1 imposter kill all the crewmates without being sussed out? I even camp vent.

Comment: The strategy to winning as single impostor against 9 crewmates is considerably different (and significantly harder) than in common scenarios where a single impostor needs to kill 3-4 crewmates. Closing this one as a duplicate is quite unfair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really kill crewmates faster, but there's a few tips you can do to keep dead bodies from being reported.

1. Try to kill crewmates at places where there are few tasks; this way people will take longer to notice it. Ex: North side of cafeteria.
2. If you have a partner Impostor try to organize a double-kill (two impostors kill two crewmates in one area.
3. Sabotages help too. You can turn off the lights to kill people without them noticing. They can also be used to draw players to one area. If a crewmate decides to do a task while everyone else is fixing the oxygen then they can be easily be picked off.

So overall being an impostor requires strategy. You can't just kill anyone anywhere. Hope this helped!